# Reference request: For manifolds $M,N$ the space $C^0(M,N)$ is in general not path-connected.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I am currently looking at a paper analysing the path-connectedness of Sobolev spaces between manifolds. One theorem states that under certain conditions the Sobolev space is path-connected iff the space of continuous functions between manifolds $C^0(M,N)$ is path-connected. It is remarked that this is, in general, is not the case (, which in turn motivates further procedure).

Does anyone know a reference for the remark?

Comment: Consider the case of maps of circle to itself. Do you know about fundamental group? Then you can finish it yourself.

Comment: Oh, i feel stupid now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general $C^0(M, N)$ is not path connected. If it is path connected, it means that all $f:M\to N$ are homotopic to a constant map. There are lots of examples where this is not true:

- If $\pi_1(N)$ is nontrivial, $C^0(\mathbb S^1, N)$ is not path connected (similarly on higher homotopy groups),
- Then $M = N$ are compact, $C^0(N,N)$ is not path connected as the identity map $I : N\to N$ induces identity map on top homology, while constant map induces zero map on top homology,

Comment: Note that path-components of $C^0(S^k,N)$ are not quite the same thing as elements of $\pi_k(N)$, since for $\pi_k(N)$ the homotopies are required to fix the basepoint.  Instead, they are orbits of the action of $\pi_1(N)$ on $\pi_k(N)$ (for $k=1$, this action is by conjugation).